# How to access a imagelist across windows in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to access an image list across two windows in tkinter.

here is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root =  Tk()
root2 = Tk()

image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Emoji/1.png"))
image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Emoji/2.png"))

button1 = Button(root, image = image2)
button1.grid()

button2 = Button(root2, image = image1)
button2.grid()

mainloop()
```

But I am getting an `TclError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\solli\PycharmProjects\Dobble\count.py", line 36, in <module>
  button2 = Button(root2, image = image1)
File "C:\Users\solli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2650, in __init__
  Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Users\solli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
  self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

Comment: Why are you using 2 instances of ```Tk()```? It is discouraged

Comment: Don't use `Tk()` more than once. You can use a `Toplevel` window instead: `root2 = Toplevel(root)` Then you can set the title and geometry of the window like you would do with a `Tk()` window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've been able to load two images into two `tkinter` windows is by making the second window `Toplevel`

Here is a working  example.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fido
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root =  tk.Tk()

imagename1 = Image.open(
    fido.askopenfilename( title = "Load png", parent = root ))
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagename1)
button1 = tk.Button(root, image = image1)
button1.grid()
imagename1.close()
root.update()

root2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
root2.lift()
imagename2 = Image.open(
    fido.askopenfilename( title = "Load png", parent = root2 ))
image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagename2)
button2 = tk.Button(root2, image = image2)
button2.grid()
imagename2.close()

root.mainloop()
```